# Is there long long defined?

Tags: c++

Where to check if type long long is defined? I wanna do something like this:

```
#ifdef LONGLONG
#define long_long long long
#else 
#define long_long long
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LLONG_MAX` gives the maximum value representable by a `long long`; if your implementation doesn't support `long long`, it shouldn't define `LLONG_MAX`.

```
#include <limits.h>

#ifdef LLONG_MAX
#define long_long long long
#else
#define long_long long
#endif
```

This isn't a perfect solution.  `long long` isn't standard in C++03, and `long long` has been around longer than C99, so it's possible (and likely) that a compiler could support `long long` but not define `LLONG_MAX`.

If you want an integer type with a specific size, you should use `<stdint.h>` if your implementation supports it.  If your implementation doesn't support it, [Boost has an implementation of it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/cstdint.hpp).

Comment: @James my implementation supports (provides) stdint.h, I've found there something like this: #define _LONGLONG __int64, so I understand that I shall type _LONGLONG instead of LLONG_MAX and it should be ok? Really appreciate if you could answer that. Thank you.

Comment: @Knowing:  Why not just use the types defined in stdint.h?  `_LONGLONG` is defined by your implementation and is not standard, so if you want to write portable code you should not use it.

Comment: @James McNellis I found there (stdint.h) something like this: UINT64_MAX, if I use this I think it will be ok?

Comment: @Knowing:  No... `UINT64_MAX` gives you the maximum value representable by a `uint64_t`, not a `long long`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @James I'm trying to get as a result from my fnc largest possible type available.

Comment: @Knowing:  Then use `std::intmax_t` declared in `<cstdint>`.  That will be the largest signed integral type available.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than worry about whether or not a type with that name is defined, I'd `#include <climits>` and check whether or not you can find an integer type large enough for your intended use. (Although you could probably just check if `LLONG_MAX` is defined to find out if `long long` exists.)

Edit: Or, if you can assume C99 headers and types to be available, `#include <cstdint.h>` and use e.g. `int64_t` to get a 64-bit type or `int_fast64_t` to get a “fast” 64-bit type (by some compiler-specific definition of fast). Or `intmax_t` if you want the largest available type.