# error C3017: termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a for loop that has all variables defined

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(long long l = 1; l<=sqrtt; l++) ...
```

When I compile this with the `/openmp` command line option in Visual Studio 2012, it gives me

```
error C3017: termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form
```

I don't know why `'for' statement has improper form`.

What is a *proper* for statement to OpenMP? How do I apply it to my for loop?

Comment: I tried long long in MSVC and it works fine.  The problem is likely in `sqrtt`.  Make sure it's of type long long and invariant.

Comment: Yes that was the problem @Zboson. Sqrtt was a long double.

Answer (score 6):

The [OpenMP 3.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) standard prescribes a very strict form for the *for-loop* construct (see pag.39):

```
for (init-expr; test-expr; incr-expr) structured-block
```

In particular, `test-expr` must look like one of the following:

```
var relational-op b
b relational-op var
```

where *relational-op* is one of `<,<=,>,>=` and `b` is a **loop invariant** expressions of a type compatible with the type of var.

Other than that you must ensure that:

> The values of the loop control expressions of the loops associated
>   with the loop  construct must be the same for all the threads in the
>   team.

So, coming back to your case, I would check `sqrtt` to be a loop invariant and to have the same value for all threads.

#### A little side note

`long long` isn't standard in C++ prior to C++11, see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836891/771663) on SO.

Comment: +1.  It's worth pointing out that the OP is using MSVC which only supports OpenMP 2.5 (or at least less than OpenMP 3).  MSVC's implementation of OpenMP is even more restrictive in the for loop.  For example unsigned int is improper.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. I had this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < stop; i++){ 
    //My code
}
```

Then I discovered that the problem was that my variable `stop` was a *double*, so, how in my case I needed that `stop` was a *double*, I had to do a casting:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < (int)stop; i++){ 
    //My code
}
```

And then all worked :)

I hope this can help.