# floating point multiplication vs repeated addition

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, floating-point

Let `N` be an a compile time unsigned integer.

GCC can optimize

```
unsigned sum = 0;
for(unsigned i=0; i<N; i++) sum += a; // a is an unsigned integer
```

to simply  `a*N`. This can be understood since modular arithmetic says `(a%k + b%k)%k = (a+b)%k`.

However GCC will not optimize

```
float sum = 0;
for(unsigned i=0; i<N; i++) sum += a;  // a is a float
```

to `a*(float)N`.

But by using associative math with e.g. `-Ofast` I discovered that GCC can reduce this in order `log2(N)` steps.  E.g for `N=8` it can do the sum in three additions.

```
sum = a + a
sum = sum + sum // (a + a) + (a + a)
sum = sum + sum // ((a + a) + (a + a)) + ((a + a) + (a + a))
```

Though some point after `N=16` GCC goes back to doing `N-1` sums.

**My question is why does GCC not do `a*(float)N` with `-Ofast`?**

Instead of being `O(N)` or `O(Log(N))` it could be simply `O(1)`. Since `N` is known at compile time it's possible to determine if `N` fits in a float. And even if `N` is too large for a float it could do `sum =a*(float)(N & 0x0000ffff) + a*(float)(N & ffff0000)`.  In fact, I did a little test to check the accuracy and `a*(float)N` is more accurate anyway (see the code and results below).

```
//gcc -O3 foo.c
//don't use -Ofast or -ffast-math or -fassociative-math
#include <stdio.h>   
float sumf(float a, int n)
{
  float sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) sum += a;
  return sum;
}

float sumf_kahan(float a, int n)
{
  float sum = 0;
  float c = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    float y = a - c;
    float t = sum + y;
    c = (t -sum) - y;
    sum = t;
  }
  return sum;
}  

float mulf(float a, int n)
{
  return a*n;
}  

int main(void)
{
  int n = 1<<24;
  float a = 3.14159;
  float t1 = sumf(a,n);
  float t2 = sumf_kahan(a,n);
  float t3 = mulf(a,n);
  printf("%f %f %f\n",t1,t2,t3);
}
```

The result is `61848396.000000 52707136.000000 52707136.000000` which shows that multiplication and the [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) have the same result which I think shows that the multiplication is more accurate than the simple sum.

Comment: Have you considered that three add ops may be faster than a floating point multiply?  This would be consistent with it switching back to a fp multiply at N=16.

Comment: It doesn't make the optimization because the optimization is not valid; in general it produces a different result. Floating point arithmetic does not obey the usual normal arithmetic properties you expect like associativity or the distributive law. Multiplication is not repeated addition.

Comment: @R..: He (implicitly) uses `-ffast-math` which *does* allow those kind of optimizations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do

Comment: Oh, I missed that... :-(

Comment: You really like to push the limits of compilers don't you? :D That's okay, I do too, but more on the back-end.

Comment: Fun. I've found gcc *vectorizes* the sum when the "multiplier" is a function argument.

Comment: If `-Ofast` implies `-ffast-math`, then this question mixes `-ffast-math` and Kahan summation, which is not a good recipe (Kahan summation is the prototypal example of code that must not be compiled with non-compliant optimizations).

Comment: @PascalCuoq, in the test for accuracy I did not use `-Ofast` or associative math I just used `-O3` or no optimization at all.

Comment: @Ian, the compiler never switches to multiplication. That's the point. But I do agree with you that there for some small values that `O(log(n)` algorithm could be faster than the `O(1)`.

Comment: @Mysticial, I was inspired by this question by another question on SO where the OP had a complicated formula which turn out to be a constant in the loop which he did not realize. He wanted to optimize the loop. Doing `a*float(N)` would have been a lot faster and even more precise anyway.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I think I see where some confusion could be. I did not state the results of that code.  It's `61848396.000000 52707136.000000 52707136.000000`. So the multiplication and the Kahan sum get the same result.That's what I meant by the multiplication being more accurate than the simple sum.

Comment: FWIW, clang does this optimization under -ffast-math.  Fascinatingly, GCC will do it if N is *exactly* 4 (http://goo.gl/ZcERor) ... this shouldn't require fast-math because x+x+x+x always equals 4*x in default rounding, but apparently they special-cased this operation only under fast-math.

Comment: @StephenCanon, woah, Clang wins again! Sorta, I tried N = 64 and it does mult but by N=128 Clang stops doing the mult.

Comment: @Zboson: Yeah, it seems I'll be filing multiple clang bugs related to this.

Comment: @StephenCanon it's not obvious to me why "x+x+x+x always equals 4*x in default rounding" (this is why you have the floating-point tag and I don't). Are there other special cases like this? I think I though sum(x) for powers of 2 would be the same as `2^n*x` but I thought I tried that and it did not work for some larger values of n.  I guess I could ask a question about it but maybe the answer is obvious in one or two lines.

Comment: @Zboson: It's highly non-obvious (even Kahan was shocked when I told him this fact, though he immediately understood why it was true once I told him).  The simplest way to see that it's true is probably by exhaustively checking the rounding for all possible trailing bit patterns of x, if you're curious.  A deeper proof can probably be reached by proving that (2^n - 1)x + x = 2^n x if 2^n-1 is representable, and then note that x + x + x = 3x.  The property holds for 2, 3, 4, and 5; 6 is the first n for which it fails.

Comment: I'd suggest you to send it to GCC mailing list/bugtracker

Comment: @EvgeniyZh, thank you for your suggestion. I submitted a bug report to GCC. This is my first bug submission. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68105

Comment: @EvgeniyZh, I'm not sure I reported the error to the right component. I said "c" "A problem with the C compiler front end". But I am not sure this is really a front end issue. Where should I put this "bug"? Should I use "middle-end" "GCC's middle end; folks, expand_*, etc. Target dependent parts and optimization passes have their own component"?

Comment: @Zboson I believe the bug belongs into one of optimization components: ipa, tree- or rtl-optimization. I'm not pro it gcc structure though, to tell you for sure. I suggest to a send a question to the mailing list, also that may attract developers attention to the problem

Comment: float has only 23 bits of mantissa (including 1 implicit bit), but unsigned int has 32 bit mantissa, which can be concluded that when i > (2^24), all the addition sum+=a will not have any effect, because at that time "a" is 23 bits after the current "sum" in the binary representation. That might be the reason

Answer (score 2):

There are some fundamental difference between

```
 float funct( int N, float sum )
 {
     float value = 10.0;
     for( i = 0; i < N ;i ++ ) {
         sum += value;
     }
     return sum;
 }
```

and

```
float funct( int N, float sum )
{
    float value = 10.0;
    sum += value * N;
    return sum;
}
```

When the sum approaches FLT_EPSILON * larger than value, the repeated sum tends towards a no-op.  So any large value of N, would result in no change to sum for repeated addition.  For the multiplication choice, the result (value * N) needs to be FLT_EPSILON * smaller than sum for the operation to have a no-op.

So the compiler can't make the optimization, because it can't tell if you wanted the exact behavior (where multiply is better), or the implemented behavior, where the scale of  sum affects the result of the addition.